# scala - replace 2nd and 4th occurence using regex

Tags: scala

I want to replace amt_2 and amt_4 to amt_ytd_2 and amt_ytd_4 in the below string.

```
scala> val a = "select amt_1, amt_2, amt_3, amt_4 from table"
a: String = select amt_1, amt_2, amt_3, amt_4 from table

scala> val reg = """(\d+)""".r
reg: scala.util.matching.Regex = (\d+)
```

I'm able to replace all of them in one go, but how do I replace only the 2nd and 4th occurrence in the string?.

```
scala> reg.replaceAllIn(a, "_ytd_$1")
res23: String = select amt__ytd_1, amt__ytd_2, amt__ytd_3, amt__ytd_4 from table

scala>
```

I tried something like below, but not getting expected results

```
scala> var x = 0
x: Int = 0

scala> reg.replaceAllIn(a, {x+=1; if(x%2==0) "ytd" else " " })
res24: String = select amt_ , amt_ , amt_ , amt_  from table

scala>
```

Comment: You only want to replace the second and fourth?

Comment: yes.. second and the fourth using the regex way

Comment: do you want replace the string amt_2 and amt_4 ?

Comment: If you change your regex to `val reg = """(2|4)""".r`, your `reg.replaceAllIn(a, "_ytd_$1")` line will work. Is this not enough?

Comment: That's literally just matching on the numbers 2 or 4. Do you _need_ it to be any number which is divisible by two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pattern match with a guard condition.

```
"amt_(\\d+)".r.replaceAllIn(a, _ match {
    case m if m.group(1).toInt % 2 == 0 => s"amt__ytd_${m.group(1)}"
    case m                              => m.group(0)
  })
//res0: String = select amt_1, amt__ytd_2, amt_3, amt__ytd_4 from table
```

---

**update**

It appears you want the 2nd and 4th match, not necessarily the matches ending with `_2` and `_4`. Try this.

```
//string to modify
val a = "select amt_1, amt_2, amt_3, amt_4 from table"

//all the matches
val ms = "amt_(\\d+)".r.findAllMatchIn(a).toVector

//modify 2nd & 4th match (i.e. at index 1 & 3) if they exist
Vector(1,3).foldRight(a)(
  (x,s) => ms.lift(x).fold(s)(m => s.patch(m.start(1), "_ydt_", 0)))
//res0: String = select amt_1, amt__ydt_2, amt_3, amt__ydt_4 from table
```

Notice that this will modify the 4th match, at index 3, *only if that many were found*. Likewise for the 2nd match at index 1. So if 0 or 1 matches are found, no mods are made. If 2 or 3 matches are found then only 1 mod is made (at the 2nd match).

Comment: actually I want to check against the 2nd and 4th occurence of the match without using any mutable variable..

Comment: @stack0114106; As you can see, this doesn't use any mutable variables. In this case I use the guard condition to test for any `amt_` number that's even. That can be easily changed to test just for `2` and `4`.

Comment: actually gtosto answer is correct as it check the 2nd and 4th occurence and replaces it.. your solution also works coincidentally.. my test data is somewhat misleading and hence this question.

Comment: great it works.. as I expected it doesn't use mutable variables.. it looks complex for me to understand.. will take some time.. btw is it possible to avoid the ````+4```` in the patch?

Comment: generalizing it.. would I consider this to be a solution for replacing the nth match in a string without using mutable variables.. ?..

Comment: `+4` has been removed. Yes, this can be used to modify any nth match (at index n-1). Just change numbers (index values) that you `foldRight` over. Note: we `foldRight` over a collection of _increasing_ index values. If the index values were decreasing then we would `foldLeft` over them. It won't work if the index values are unordered.

Answer (score 1):

try using replaceSomeIn

```
val a = "select amt_1, amt_2, amt_3, amt_4 from table"

val reg = """(\d+)""".r

var c = 0
reg.replaceSomeIn(a, m => {
  c = c+1
  val x = m.group(0)
  if ( c == 2 || c == 4)
    Some("a")
  else 
    Some(x)
})
```

Comment: your answer is close to what I'm expecting... I dont want to check x==2 or 4.. in my question, I was checking the nth occurence against 2 or 4 so I used x%2==0, by incrementing the var x.

Comment: In that case you need a &amp;quot;global&amp;quot; var. I&#39;ll update my answer as soon as i can

Comment: yes.. now it's correct.. anyways to avoid the mutable variable c

Comment: I believe it isn't viable, like match doesn't carry any occurrence counter or state

Answer (score 0):

```
val a = "select amt_1, amt_2, amt_3, amt_4 from table"

val reg = """((?=\d)(?=[^13]))""".r
reg.replaceAllIn(a, "_ytd_$1")
```

Try this

Comment: This does the opposite of what you want. Get rid of the `^` (or change it to `((?=\d)(?![^24]))` if you're feeling spicy) and it'll work.

Comment: The result is this : res0: String = select amt__ytd_1, amt_2, amt__ytd_3, amt_4 from table

Comment: The original questions says "I want to replace amt_2 and amt_4 to amt_ytd_2 and amt_ytd_4" - IMO you'd be better off doing a positive match on 2 & 4 rather than a negative match on 1 & 3, but I guess that'd be up to the OP.

Comment: Yeah i guess you are right, but this works, he decide if he wants to change :)